# Using [Inspectable] to build object inspector IN flex

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex

I'm building a little tool that lets user to place some geometric figures on screen and then move them around and change their properties. I'm quite new to as3/flex.

Figures are represented as objects in as3. So we've got Circle, Triangle, Rectangle classes with different properties.

What I like to do is to display some kind of "object inspector" when user selects a figure. This inspector window would resemble similar thing found in many IDEs.

Now the question is: Is it possible to take advantage from as3 [Inspectable] tag to obtain list of properties and enable changing them at runtime?

If it's not possible then how would you approach this problem without writing type specific code to edit each object?

**Edit:**

Just to clarify. Consider this example:

```
public class Shape { /* ... */ }

public class Triangle extends Shape { 
  public var a:Number;
  public var h:Number;
  //...
}

public class Circle extends Shape {
  public var r:Number;
  public var name:String;
  //...
}
```

I want to give the user an ability to edit `a`, `h` from `Triangle` and `r`, `name` from `Circle`.

From what I imagine now, I could follow two paths:

1. Make `Triangle` and `Circle` implement `IMyInspectable` and write custom `getProperties():Dictionary`, `getProperty(name:String):Object` and `setProperty(name:String, value:Object):void` methods for each type. This would involve utterly unelegant switch-spaghetti.
2. I forgot when I was typing the solution number one. :(

Comment: You can't fix a knife wound with a band-aid.

Comment: I've discovered this: http://www.negush.net/blog/listing-the-properties-of-an-object/

The problem is that it's not working for me :[

Comment: Runtime of my app of course. "then at least select a different tag" what tag? :) 

My main problem is that I don't know how to implement something like that, not to mention making tags for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [describeType](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#describeType%28%29) to introspect objects.  I would probably take a very different approach, though.

Create an interface, something like IObjectIWantToCreatePropertyWindowFor and have your relevant shape objects implement this.  The interface could somehow define the list of properties you want edtiable on the object.  I might even make this an array of Value Objects that contain the property name, a display name, and the type of editor it should have.  Each object can hard code this list of properties in it.

The property window could be written to redraw itself based on the interface values.  Most likely I'd do that using a List class with an [itemRendererfunction](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/SkinnableDataContainer.html#itemRendererFunction) somehow.

What you want to do doesn't sound hard, but it's not trivial either.

---

Nooga asked a more detailed explanation.  This is all psuedo code, but:

1) Create an interface:

```
package com.propertyInspector
{

    public interface IPropertyInspectable
    {

        function get inspectableProperties(  ):array;
    }
}
```

2) Create a class that implements IPropertyInspectable

```
package com.propertyInspector
{

    public class myClass implements IPropertyInspectable
    {

        public var property1 :String
        public var property2 : Int

        public function get inspectableProperties():Array{
          return [{name:'property1',type:'String'},{name:'property2',type:'String'}, ]
        }
    }
}
```

3) Create your property inspector.

```
<s:List dataProvider="{someSelectedObjectThatImplementsIPropertyInspectable.inspectableProperties}">
 <s:itemRenderer>
   <s:Label text="data.name"/><s:TextInput />
 </s:itemRenderer>
</s:List>
```

You'll have to figure out how to pass the objects into the property inspector.  And the property objects in inspectableProperties will probably need a reference to the actual object they refer to so that the List can display default values.

And you can use an itemRenderer function to display different editable approaches based on the type.  a TextInput for Strings, a NumericStepper for numbers, and so on.

Comment: I think that describeType would be an overkill here. I think that the most elegant solution would be not to write code for every type. And that's the problem here :(

Comment: @nooga Using your suggestion of using the Inspectable metadta; I thought that describeType was the only way to get at custom metadata at runtime.  Were you suggesting an alternate?  I believe my "interface approach" allows you to use the same "property inspector" for any given type.  The code you have to write for each "object" would be "as complicated as you need it to be".

Comment: Agree with flextras, there is no reason to use metadata or annotations in this case it offers no benefit I can see.  If you were to have to write an annotation for each type to describe the property and potential values what's the difference if you do so in your own object rather than in metadata?  Using an interface for a "Inspectable" object should just be a matter of having it return a collection of property/value objects, you can even easily re-use definitions of a particular property/value object as opposed to repetition created by doing it in metadata.

Comment: Could You provide a short example? I'm afraid that I don't completely understand flextras approach :(

Comment: @nooga I edited my answer to add some psuedo code and hopefully to better explain the approach.  If you need more than that, I am available as a consultant for hire.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com Thanks alot! I will play with your idea.